# Use substitution to find out the running time of T(1) = 1 ; T(n) = 4T(n/3) + n

Tags: algorithm, runtime

I've got to this point 4^logn + 3n[(4/3)^logn -1] and am having trouble finishing it.

Log is base 3.(Wasn't sure how to do subscripts and exponents.)

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect spot to use the Master Theorem. In your case, we want to write the recurrence in the form

> T(n) = aT(n / b) + O(n<sup>d</sup>).

With your recurrence, you get

- a = 4
- b = 3
- c = 1

Since log<sub>b</sub>a > d, the Master Theorem says that this solves to O(n<sup>log<sub>3</sub> 4</sup>).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Masters theorem is general tool for such problems , but if you want the specific solution by substitution then it as follows :

```
T(n) = 4T(n/3) + n
T(n) = 4(4T(n/9) + n/3) + n = 4^2T(n/9) + (4/3)n + n
T(n) = 4^2(4T(n/27) + n/3^2) + (4/3)n + n = 4^3T(n/27) + (4/3)^2n + (4/3)n + n
T(n) = 4^kT(n/3^k) + (4/3)^(k-1)n + (4/3)^(k-2)n....

boundary condition 

n/3^k = 1, k = log3(n)
T(1) = 1
geometric series summation
T(n) = 4^log3(n) + 1((4/3)^log3(n) - 1)/(log3(n)-1)*n
using log rules
T(n) = n^(log3(4)) + n^(1+log3(4/3))/(log3(n)-1) - n/(log3(n)-1) 
T(n) = n^(log3(4)) + n^(1+log3(4)-log(3))/(log3(n)-1) - n/(log3(n)-1)
T(n) = n^(log3(4)) + n^(log3(4))/(log3(n)-1) - n/(log3(n)-1)
T(n) = O(n^log3(4))
```